# Why is in adding a collection with its own ID in an entity, i always get the principal ID instead of the collection's id?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am adding a collection into an existing set of data. I have a **student** where its **subjects** are still `null`. So what i am doing is to `post` the collection into that **student**.

Here is my `code`:

```
[HttpPost("{id}/subjects")]
public async Task<ActionResult<object>> PostStudentSubject(string id, Subject item)
{
    // this is to get whole subject model using id
    Subject subj = await _context.Subjects.FindAsync(item.Id);

    // this is to get student model through the given id in parameter
    Student stud = await _context.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);

    if (stud == null){
        return NotFound();
    }

    // this is to remove the "subj" to avoid an Exception:
    // "The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified"
    _context.Subjects.Remove(subj);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // and this is now to add a new object Subject to the
    // collection of subjects in the student
    stud.Subjects.Add(new Subject { Id = subj.Id });
    // some subject properties are omitted...
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(stud);
}
```

It returns `OK` but Swagger response returns these:

**Server Response**

> Code -> Undocumented, Details -> Error: OK

**Responses**

> Code -> 200, Description -> Success

The visible **PROBLEM** is that the **subject's ID** will change into the **student's ID**. Why is this happening? And on what part I am getting this?

**SUBJECT**

```
    public class Subject
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        // some codes omitted ...

        [ForeignKey("Id")]
        public Student student {get; set;}
    }
```

**STUDENT**

```
    public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        // some codes omitted ...

        public IList<Subject> Subjects {get; set;} = new List<Subject>();
    }
```

Comment: Can you include any mapping/config for your student and subject mapping, and the entity definitions? This sounds like somehow your subject is configured as a 1-to-1 with Student. or the FK mappings are misconfigured.

Comment: @StevePy i already added it

Comment: The foreign key attribute is your problem.. Eluding to that in a solution for code example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the ForeignKey:

```
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public Student student {get; set;}
```

The Subject table should have a StudentId column to point at the applicable student. As it is, you're telling Subject that it's PK should be the Student ID. (Like as in a 1-to-1 relationship)

In EF if this is code-first:

```
public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } // ID for the Subject

    // some codes omitted ...

    public string StudentId { get; set; } // FK to the student.
    [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
    public Student student {get; set;}
}
```

However the relationship between Student and Subject should probably be a Many-to-Many where many students can be associated to many of the same subjects. (a student has many subjects, and a subject has many students)

To do this you'd want a linking table called something like StudentSubjects.

```
StudentSubjects
StudentId [PK] [FK -> Students]
SubjectId [PK] [FK -> Subjects]
```

EF can manage this table automatically so long as it just contains the composite key and no other fields. Otherwise you need to define it as an entity and provide the mapping manually.

```
public class Student
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; } 

   public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; } = new List<Subject>();
}

public class Subject
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; } 

   public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; } = new List<Student>();
}
```

if CodeFirst this should set up a StudentSubjects (or SubjectStudents) table to manage the relationship. Otherwise you can map the HasMany.WithMany and define the table, left and right key relationship...

I.e. for Student EntityTypeConfiguration

```
// EF6 Syntax. EF Core will be a tad different /w IEntityTypeConfiguration<Student> implementation.

public class StudentConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
   public StudentConfiguration()
   {
      HasMany(x => x.Subjects)
         .WithMany(x => x.Students)
         .Map(x => x.ToTable("StudentSubjects").MapLeftKey("StudentId").MapRightKey("SubjectId"));
   }
}
```

I strongly recommend not using strings for PKs. They are quite large for storage and indexing, and you can't leverage using DB-side identity or defaults such as NewSequentialId() [GUIDs]

Comment: My solution was to remove the `ForeignKey` attribute. I used a `Single Navigation` without having `ForeignKey`

Comment: With a Student reference on a Course each course instance will only have a reference to a single student, and you may end up "moving" the course when you try adding it to a second student. Otherwise you would have duplicate courses with different PKs with the same details, one for each student in that course. If there are other related questions ask away. :)